# CSS selectors have no effect

Tags: html, css

This is a crappy issue and I am truly sorry to ask this. But I have been programming PHP for hours and now trying to display it on a simple html layout. I need more coffee and my eyes are tired, woke up too early...

**Anyway the issue is,** that for some reason my css styles that should affect the text stylings has no effect what so ever on the layout. Which is a bit odd that the border settings and paddings do work, but font-weight or the background-color does not.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Visitor logs</title>
  <style>
  html {
  }

  body {
  }

  .first_row {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: red;
  }

  td {
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr class="first_row">
      <td>IP-address</td>
      <td>Last visited</td>
      <td>Rough location</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested and your code is fine! Can you add more detail? A screenshot for example

Comment: can you provide snapshot?

Comment: I would crack open the developer tools in my browser and use the Inspector to see what CSS rules are affecting the particular HTML element. Somewhere, a different bit of CSS with greater specificity is trumping the selector you’re looking at

Comment: Another example of your code working: https://jsfiddle.net/gbfrko95/

Comment: This is odd. If I copy-paste my code to a new html-file it works fine. But the original which I have issue with, still does not work. It is located here if you wish to check it out https://www.lieksa.info/panel/layout_log.html

Answer (score 2):

Add this code:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.first_row {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="first_row">
        <td>IP-address</td>
        <td>Last visited</td>
        <td>Rough location</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="second_row">
        <td>IP-address2</td>
        <td>Last visited2</td>
        <td>Rough location2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**See This Also:**

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.first_row {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
}

tr:not(.first_row) td:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}


td {
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="first_row">
        <td>IP-address</td>
        <td>Last visited</td>
        <td>Rough location</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="second_row">
        <td>IP-address2</td>
        <td>Last visited2</td>
        <td>Rough location2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used `thead` with `th` for heading of table

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
  padding:4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Visitor logs</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>IP-address</th>
        <th>Last visited</th>
        <th>Rough location</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add **cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"** in table tag or add **table{border-collapse: collapse;}** in your css.

```css
.first_row {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr class="first_row">
    <td>IP-address</td>
    <td>Last visited</td>
    <td>Rough location</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```